# Spring boot appengine application not picking environment variables from app.yaml in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a spring boot application running on Google AppEngine Standard environment. My app.yaml is something like this:

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
service: appinapp
handlers:
  - url: /(.*)
    script: auto
    secure: always
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 2
env_variables:
  VAR1: "var1"
  VAR2: "var2"
  VAR3: "var3"
```

My application.yml is something like this:

```
var1: ${VAR1:myvar1}
var2: ${VAR2:myvar2}
var3: ${VAR3:myvar3}
```

Whenever I deploy the application, the variables in `application.yml` always take the default variables, i.e., `myvar1`, `myvar2`, `myvar3` instead of `var1`, `var2`, `var3`. I am not able to figure out why this happens. Note that I have 2 different app.yaml for staging and production. For staging it is `staging_app.yaml` and for the production, it is `prod_app.yaml`.

Any help here is much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I checked uploaded files in the AppEngine debug mode and found my YAML files are not getting updated every time I deploy a new build in the application. Only the jar file gets updated

Comment: How exactly are you [deploying the application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_application)?

Comment: @Daniel Ocando I am deploying it using the following command - `gcloud apl deploy path/to/staging_app.yaml` or  `gcloud apl deploy path/to/prod_app.yaml` where the yaml file and jar file are in the same folder

Comment: How do you generate the JAR file? Do you get the same result if you try to deploy the application using [Apache Maven and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-maven#setting_up_maven)? I'm just trying to discard if it's an issue with the command you are using to deploy the application or the application itself.

Comment: I haven't tried the maven plugin because of the structure of my CI/CD pipeline

Comment: I think that according to the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) the variables being overwritten by the application.yml file is intended behavior. In order to avoid uploading this file to App Engine add the application.yml file to the [.gcloudignore file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) or create your own file and use the [--ignore-file= flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--ignore-file) when running `gcloud app deploy`.